# html drag and drop different items

Tags: html, drag

I have a drag and drop html5 function which works fine :

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

So I set it on two elements lets say those two:

```
    <div id="div1" id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> 
      <h3> Monday </h3> 
    </div>
    <div id="div1" id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> 
      <h3> Tuesday </h3> 
    </div>
```

It works fine with the first element, but when I try to drag and drop the second one, it keeps droping the first one. I have also tested it on multiple items: only the first item drops when I drag any item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you have 2 elements with the same ID: `drag1`. You should avoid giving your elements the same ID

Comment: Merci bcp Mister Laszlo